# Should I back up my Google Authenticator codes to my Google Account?

Tags: authentication, account-security, multi-factor

I just opened the Google Authenticator app and it says: "Sign in to back up your codes to your Google Account".

How is that secure?

I mean, wouldn't doing that essentially defeat the purpose of two-factor authentication (2FA), since it'd let anyone who figures out the password to your Google Account log in to any account for which you've stored the password in Google Password Manager and the 2FA code in Google Authenticator?

Google's announcement [Google Authenticator now supports Google Account synchronization](https://security.googleblog.com/2023/04/google-authenticator-now-supports.html) doesn't seem to answer my question.

##### Related

- [Is 2FA based on Google Authenticator Real?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/254841/13888)

Comment: It's the same problem with any TOTP backup process. People had the same question when LastPass allowed it as an option a few years ago. Remember that you don't have to do it. It's just a convenience.